Calling GraphViz dot process using Javas Runtime.getRuntime().exec() and passing in a file name doesn't work but echoing input works
For some reason whenever I execute Graphviz dot using Java's Runtime.getRuntime().exec() in two different ways (one echoing the input, one passing in the filename) - only echoing works.
For eg. this doesn't work (produces 0 bytes)
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", "-c", "dot -Tsvg FILE_NAME.dot"});

But this does:
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", "-c", "echo 'digraph { A -> B }' | dot -Tsvg"});

here is the rest of my code:
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", "-c", "echo 'digraph { A -> B }' | dot -Tsvg"});
InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("out.txt");

byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
IOUtils.closeQuietly(bufferedInputStream);
IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);


Don't use Runtime. Use this new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"bash", "-c", "dot -Tsvg FILE_NAME.dot"}).inheritIO().start(); That's all you need (at first at least)

Can't reproduce. It works fine on my machine. The file FILE_NAME.dot probably doesn't exist on your machine or is not in the current directory. You are probably starting the program in a different directory than you think. You are ignoring any error messages dot might be outputting. Try new BufferedInputStream(process.getErrorStream()).transferTo(System.err);

Thanks @k314159 - the file wasn't exactly missing but something similar - I was writing to file right before running the exec command and wasn't flushing - causing the exec to see an empty file.

Figured it out - the actual issue was that I was writing the graph.dot file right before executing the dot command. However, I was not flushing the writer causing the exec command to see an empty file! So for example:
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("graph.dot"))
writer.write("digraph { A -> B }\n");
writer.flush(); // ---> WAS MISSING THIS! <---


Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", "-c", "dot -Tsvg graph.dot"});
InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("out.svg");

byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
IOUtils.closeQuietly(bufferedInputStream);
IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);


You might want to close the writer too. Preferably using try-with-resources.

The odd thing is that dot doesn't seem to complain when given an empty file
